# DoubleClick captured in my UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

As I bet I can tell the following is happening in my Excel 2013 macro:

1. Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick is calling a form
2. Some logic populates and shows the form
3. The double click event is captured by the form as an undesired selection in a listbox

Is there a correct way to suppress the double click in the middle of the subroutine?  I have ideas for getting around it (sleeping the thread works, re-positioning the form works, locking and unlocking the listbox based on other events works)  Those are all poor workarounds and I am hoping for a built-in solution that I am just not aware of.

(And setting Cancel = True does not work because I believe setting only kicks in once the code is finished running.  The double click becomes a selection in the middle of the subroutines)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, when you double click a cell what happens?, and what do you want to happen or don't want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the form you are launching from the macro is catching the same double click event try the following:

1) Have your macro call a new sub routine via 'Application.OnTime()' schedule it to run just long enough in the future to pass the 'physical click', maybe 1s. Instead of directly calling Form.Show(), as you are currently doing.

2) Your new subroutine just has to do: Form.Show(), and whatever else you deem necessary.

Comment: Nope.  EnableEvents would suppress the BeforeDoubleClick macro itself, I am trying to ignore the physical clicks inside a macro called by BeforeDoubleClick

Comment: So, I am not sure I follow, correct me if I am wrong:

1) You double click, a macro fires
2) The macro launches a form
3) The form also captures the SAME double click and breaks

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  Although breaks is a bit strong, unintentionally selects an item on my UserForm

Comment: As I poorly stated in my question ("sleeping the thread works"), I know how to hack around the problem using various methods.  I am wondering if there's a built in or idiomatic way to solve this issue